# Load generator machine (windows) reaching to 100% CPU

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am running 2250 users test from AWS windows VM, Following are the details.

Windows
RAM: 32GB
CPU: 8 Core

Once test reaches to 600 concurrent users the cpu is going 100% utilization. The action taken to resolve this,(Using Jmeter for test)

- Increased the Heap size (HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx12288m)
- Removed lisners from the test.
- Running test from NON GUI mode.

Still Load generator machine reaching to 100%. What whould be the best solution to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: Get something like VisualVM and see what CPU is doing - that would be the first step

Answer (score 0):

First check you follow best practices in your test:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html
- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

Then it would be better to use a linux machine instead of Windows as it usually scales better.

Finally try increasing the machine type to give it more CPUs.

Comment: I tried with Ubuntu machine observed the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be switching from single machine having 32 GB of RAM to 3 machines having 12 GB of RAM and run [JMeter in distributed mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) as your test seems to be very CPU intensive.

See [What’s the Max Number of Users You Can Test on JMeter?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter) for more comprehensive explanation of JMeter virtual users limits and what needs to be done to overcome them.

Comment: Currently, i am using total 2 distributed machines to achieve 4500 test. Shall i increase to 4 machines? Do we have any other solution?

Comment: If you lack CPU I'm afraid this is the only option. You can also try to determine why your test is so CPU intensive by running your JMeter test under a profiler tool telemetry like [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/). Also make sure you are following recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article.